# unity php WWW is not work

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I want to update my score using php with unity

I have **session_score.php**

```
<?php
//session_score.php

session_start(); 

$score = $_REQUEST['score'];
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) return;


$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "graduate", "bitnami", "my_game");
$sql = "update UserAccount set score=$score where userid='$userid';";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die("first query error");

$sql = "select userid, score from UserAccount;";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die("second query error");

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    echo"{$row->userid} : {$row->score}\n";
}

?>
```

and this is unity C# code that is attached to the UI button

```
int score;
public void Score()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("score", score);
    WWW w = new WWW("http://localhost/session_score.php", form);
}
```

when I click button,the score does not update..
I don't know the reason 
please help..

Comment: Is your session-id being sent along with the request you are making?

Comment: Which platform did you select on Unity? I noticed that certain platform's implementation of WWWForm does not always work as expected.